# How can I assign values (-1, 0, 1) to the difference between consecutive rows in a MySQL table having 20 columns and 20 rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table from MySQL called References with 20 columns and 20 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE bop_ppy 
( start_time DATETIME (6)
, end_time DATETIME (6)
, high DECIMAL (5,2)
, low DECIMAL  (5,2)
, close DECIMAL (5,2)
, vol DECIMAL (5,2)
, vol_avg DECIMAL (5,2)
, range_ DECIMAL (5,2)
, poc_ DECIMAL (5,2)
, va_h DECIMAL (5,2)
, va_l DECIMAL (5,2)
, va_range DECIMAL (5,2)
, tpot INT
, tpo_ab INT
, tpo_bl INT
, sf DECIMAL (5,2)
, tff DECIMAL (5,2)
, rf INT
, vty DECIMAL (5,2)
, dists INT).
```

The data is updated daily.

I need to compute the difference between consecutive rows, for each column, except the start_time and end_time columns, which are incremented by 1 day) such that if the value on day 2 is higher than the value on day 1, we assign +1 to the difference; if the value on day 2 is less than the value on day 1, we assign -1 to that difference; if the value on day 2 is equal to the value on day 1, we assign 0 to that difference. The idea is to generate a new table/view that shows only the tallies, instead of the original values.

Each row corresponds to one day's data.
I am using MySQL Workbench.

I have tried to first do a self join of the table and then assign dummy variables to the difference between consecutive rows, but so far this has not worked.I don't know how to make this work anymore. Please could someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ORDER BY start_date` gets the rows into the day1, day2 order, and you're not concerned about handling cases where two rows have the same start_date, and aren't concerned with any "gaps" in start_date, then something like this would return you the +1, 0, -1 or NULL tallies you are looking for. On the first row returned, there won't be a previous row to compare to, so all of the diff_ values for those rows will be NULL.

```
SELECT d.start_date
     , d.diff_high
     , d.diff_low
     , d.diff_close
     , d.diff_vol
     , d.diff_vol_avg
     , d.diff_range_
     , d.diff_poc_
     , d.diff_va_h
     , d.diff_va_l
     , d.diff_va_range
     , d.diff_tpot
     , d.diff_tpo_ab
     , d.diff_tpo_bl
     , d.diff_sf
     , d.diff_tff
     , d.diff_rf
     , d.diff_vty
     , d.diff_dists
  FROM ( SELECT t.start_date
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.high     ,@high     ) - @high     ) AS diff_high
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.low      ,@low      ) - @low      ) AS diff_low
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.close    ,@close    ) - @close    ) AS diff_close
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.vol      ,@vol      ) - @vol      ) AS diff_vol
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.vol_avg  ,@vol_avg  ) - @vol_avg  ) AS diff_vol_avg
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.range_   ,@range_   ) - @range_   ) AS diff_range_
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.poc_     ,@poc_     ) - @poc_     ) AS diff_poc_
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.va_h     ,@va_h     ) - @va_h     ) AS diff_va_h
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.va_l     ,@va_l     ) - @va_l     ) AS diff_va_l
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.va_range ,@va_range ) - @va_range ) AS diff_va_range
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.tpot     ,@tpot     ) - @tpot     ) AS diff_tpot
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.tpo_ab   ,@tpo_ab   ) - @tpo_ab   ) AS diff_tpo_ab
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.tpo_bl   ,@tpo_bl   ) - @tpo_bl   ) AS diff_tpo_bl
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.sf       ,@sf       ) - @sf       ) AS diff_sf
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.tff      ,@tff      ) - @tff      ) AS diff_tff
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.rf       ,@rf       ) - @rf       ) AS diff_rf
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.vty      ,@vty      ) - @vty      ) AS diff_vty
              , SIGN( IFNULL( t.dists    ,@dists    ) - @dists    ) AS diff_dists
              , @high       := t.high     AS c1
              , @low        := t.low      AS c2
              , @close      := t.close    AS c3
              , @vol        := t.vol      AS c4 
              , @vol_avg    := t.vol_avg  AS c5
              , @range_     := t.range_   AS c6
              , @poc_       := t.poc_     AS c7
              , @va_h       := t.va_h     AS c8
              , @va_l       := t.va_l     AS c9
              , @va_range   := t.va_range AS c10
              , @tpot       := t.tpot     AS c11
              , @tpo_ab     := t.tpo_ab   AS c12
              , @tpo_bl     := t.tpo_bl   AS c13
              , @sf         := t.sf       AS c14
              , @tff        := t.tff      AS c15
              , @rf         := t.rf       AS c16
              , @vty        := t.vty      AS c17
              , @dists      := t.dists    AS c18
           FROM ( SELECT @high       := NULL
                       , @low        := NULL
                       , @close      := NULL
                       , @vol        := NULL
                       , @vol_avg    := NULL
                       , @range_     := NULL
                       , @poc_       := NULL
                       , @va_h       := NULL
                       , @va_l       := NULL
                       , @va_range   := NULL
                       , @tpot       := NULL
                       , @tpo_ab     := NULL
                       , @tpo_bl     := NULL
                       , @sf         := NULL
                       , @tff        := NULL
                       , @rf         := NULL
                       , @vty        := NULL
                       , @dists      := NULL
                ) i
          CROSS
           JOIN bop_ppy t
          ORDER BY t.start_time
       ) d
 ORDER BY d.start_time
```

If you want to replace those NULL values with a zero, you could wrap the expressions in the outer query with IFNULL(expr,0).

This handles a NULL value for a column as representing "no change", the same as the previous value. (If the value is unknown, we don't know if it's higher or lower.)

If you don't want a zero, and want to return a NULL when that happens, remove the IFNULL wrapper functions and second argument, and leave just the reference to the table column.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's done by index, but since your data gets updated daily, you can play with dates. For that, you'd need to execute a simple nested select. Something like this would do:

```
Select start_time, high - (select distinct high from table as b where TO_DAYS(a.start_time)-TO_DAYS(b.start_time)=1) from table as a
```

This is an example for high. Feel free to extrapolate.

The meaning of this is that for each row we now conduct another select, looking for a record with the time difference of one day. Then we take the value of that record and compare it to the current one.

If you need to flip the results, just replace 1 with -1.